# Django Rest Framework Create and Update user profile

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building a DRF project and have enabled user authentication and registration using **django-allauth** and **django-rest-auth**. A new user is registered by providing username, email, password1 and password 2.

I want to create a user profile when a user is created, however he would have to enter anything related to profile while registration. User can edit this profile afterwards, whenever he wants. My user profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, )
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, )
    ...
    ...
```

and in serializers.py I have:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

I saw some posts which added following methods to Profile model:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

with them, user was created but not the profile, and I got error `IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'age' cannot be null")`

What is the most elegant way of creating, and updating such a profile?

Comment: about that error age cannot be null, may be you can do in age property, null = True instead of blank = True

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried your suggestion but it then throws No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it error, however profile and user both are created

Comment: Which also I fixed by adding EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

Answer (score 0):

to eliminate IntegrityError change

from :

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
```

to:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
```

however, i don't know if that relationship suit your specification